# Laravel app running in Docker cannot fetch data from MySQL database located on VirtualBox virtual machine (SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused)

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker

On my PC I am running Windows 10. I have a virtual machine that runs Ubuntu 18.04. I have a Laravel project that runs on Docker. I have a MySQL server that runs on my virtual machine.  I use docker-compose.yml and Dockerfile to build the project. I do NOT have a MySQL database container: MySQL runs on my virtual machine.

My problem is that I cannot access my MySQL database called 'mydatabase'. Whenever I do `php artisan migrate` or go to my project at `localhost:8080` I get the error

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `sometable`)
```

I can run the project if I launch it on a computer that has an Ubuntu operating system. But not with virtual machine. I can access my MySQL server from virtual machine with

`mysql --host=127.0.0.1 -u root -p` and my password is also `root`.

.env file

```
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
HOSTNAME=b2d4219c8143
APP_NAME=myLaravelApp
APP_URL=http://localhost
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
DB_DATABASE=mydatabase
_=/usr/bin/env
PWD=/var/www/html
DB_PASSWORD=root
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=base64:C1IQl08HeaUSPfahtrZLL1lL81n3ELMmJd9Tkli6CtA=
DB_USERNAME=root
SHLVL=6
HOME=/root
LOG_CHANNEL=file
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '1'
services:
  web:
    build:
      context: ./
    working_dir: /var/www/html
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    environment:
         - DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
         - HOSTNAME=b2d4219c8143
         - DB_DATABASE=mydatabase
         - PWD=/var/www/html
         - DB_PASSWORD=root
         - SHLVL=3
         - HOME=/root
         - DB_USERNAME=root
         - LOG_CHANNEL=file
         - DB_CONNECTION=mysql
         - APP_NAME=fes
         - APP_ENV=local
         - APP_KEY=base64:C1IQl08HeaUSPfahtrZLL1lL81n3ELMmJd9Tkli6CtA=
         - APP_DEBUG=true
         - APP_URL=http://localhost
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y php-gd
RUN apt-get -y install php7.2-zip

COPY entrypointcust.sh /entrypointcust.sh

RUN chmod +x /entrypointcust.sh

EXPOSE 80
```

My ipv4 address on virtual machine

```
10.0.2.15
```

Any suggestions why I cannot connect to my database?

`DB_HOST=localhost` in .env file doesn't work either.

Comment: hello, first i want to know: wich version of laravel do you run ? because your .env file is not conforme to normal .env files
second, your DB server is connected to 10.0.2.15, but in your env file you put "127.0.0.1" so you will never get access to your DB .
then, verify your password if it is correct ?

Comment: also check your ports in your docker , it should use: 
      - 8889:3306

Comment: There needs to be a virtual LAN connection from inside your Docker container to the IP of the Virtual Box VM. This is tricky - there is a direct connection from your container to the host (there is a magic DNS name of `host.docker.internal` available) but to the VM (or inside the VM) is harder. Could you install MySQL on your Windows host? That would make things easier.